# check if there exists a[i] = 2*a[j] in an unsorted array a?

Tags: algorithm

Given a unsorted sequence of a[1,...,n] of integers, give an O(nlogn) runtime algorithm to check there are two indices i and j such that a[i] =2*a[j]. The algorithm should return i=0 and j=2 on input 4,12,8,10 and false on input 4,3,1,11.

I think we have to sort the array anyways which is O(nlogn). I'm not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that the first step is sorting the array.

Once the array is sorted, you can find out whether a given element is inside the array in `O(log n)` time. So if for every of the `n` elements, you check for the inclusion of another element in  `O(log n)` time, you end up with a runtime of `O(n log n)`.

Does that help you?

Comment: I'm choosing this as the right answer because even though @amit answer was elegant it assumes we have twice the space and a hash function of O(1). If I could choose two answers I would have chose Steve answer too.

Comment: Hey you still need to keep track of the original indices so still need extra space :)

Comment: @VictorParmar The assignment doesn't say you need to return the indices. "Check whether ..." sounds to me like it's asking for a boolean function (so no need to remember indices).

Answer (score 12):

Note: **that can be done on `O(n)`**<sup>1</sup> on average, using a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

```
set <- new hash set
for each x in array:
   set.add(2*x)
for each x in array:
   if set.contains(x): 
        return true
return false
```

**Proof:**

=>

If there are 2 elements `a[i]` and `a[j]` such that `a[i] = 2 * a[j]`, then when iterating first time, we inserted `2*a[j]` to the set when we read `a[j]`. On the second iteration, we find that `a[i] == 2* a[j]` is in set, and return true.

<=

If the algorithm returned true, then it found `a[i]` such that `a[i]` is already in the set in second iteration. So, during first itetation - we inserted `a[i]`. That only can be done if there is a second element `a[j]` such that `a[i] == 2 * a[j]`, and we inserted `a[i]` when reading `a[j]`.

**Note:**

In order to return the indices of the elemets, one can simply use a **hash-map** instead of a set, and for each `i` store `2*a[i]` as key and `i` as value.

**Example:**

`Input = [4,12,8,10]`

first insert for each x - 2x to the hash table, and the index. You will get:

`hashTable = {(8,0),(24,1),(16,2),(20,3)}`

Now, on secod iteration you check for each element if it is in the table:

```
arr[0]: 4 is not in the table
arr[1]: 12 is not in the table
arr[2]: 8 is in the table - return the current index [2] and the value of 8 in the map, which is 0.
```

so, final output is 2,0 - as expected.

---

(1) **Complexity notice:**

In here, `O(n)` assumes `O(1)` hash function. This is not always true. If we do assume `O(1)` hash function, we can also assume sorting with radix-sort is `O(n)`, and using a post-processing of `O(n)` [similar to the one suggested by @SteveJessop in his answer], we can also achieve `O(n)` with sorting-based algorithm.

Comment: And for that matter, if a hash table is `O(n)` then sorting is also `O(n)` using a binary radix sort.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I assume there is a point in what you are saying, this makes hashing based solution `O(nlogk)` where `k` is the possible range of elements, and assuming `k >= n` [otherwise the answer is trivial from piegeonhole principle], there is no improvement in here. **I'll delete this answer in a few minutes** [just giving you time to read this comment before I do].

Comment: I think your answer is perfectly reasonable: solves the problem with good performance using tools out of the box. It's just that there's some hair-splitting about the complexity of operations on fixed-size integers that means both the hash set and the binary radix sort are in some sense "cheating" to claim `O(n)`. Or not cheating, in which case you're right that `O(n log n)` isn't a tight bound.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Then I accept your suggestion to keep it. Also: assuming range of size `k` - won't compares based sorting in this case be `O(nlognlogk)`, because each compare OP is also `O(logk)`, and we have `O(nlogn)` of those? [I might be getting a bit out of scope here].

Comment: Well, `k` traditionally denotes a Konstant, so you can stick as many `log k` in there as you like without affecting the complexity class :-) But you're right, if we want to treat `k` as non-constant we have to do more analysis than people usually bother with. The compare wouldn't be `O(1)`, and we'd have to be more specific about the hash function to determine its exact complexity: for example if it involves multiplication of two k-digit numbers that's not `O(k)`, it's at best `O(k^(1 + epsilon))`. As you say, probably beyond the scope of the intended question.

Comment: Oh, and to be fair there's another complication in favour of the hash table. Suppose hashing `m` bits is `O(m)` (which is fairly easy to arrange). Then although each hashing operation is at best `O(log k)` rather than `O(1)`, nevertheless they only add up to `O(n)`, where `n` is the total size of the input data, because each bit of input is only involved in 2 hashes. So the only difficulty is to handwave that we can always find a "good enough" hash function, irrespective of `n`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thank you for your comments. I enjoyed this discussion very much, and it opened my eyes about a few things.

Answer (score 10):

1. Sort the array (`O(n log n)`, or `O(n)` if you're willing to stretch a point about arrays of fixed-size integers)
2. Initialise two pointers ("fast" and "slow") at the start of the array (`O(1)`)
3. Repeatedly:

   1. increment "fast" until you find an even value >= twice the value at "slow"
   2. if the value at "fast" is exactly twice the value at "slow", return true
   3. increment "slow" until you find a value >= half the value at `fast`
   4. if the value at "slow" is exactly half the value at "fast", return true
4. if one of the attempts to increment goes past the end, return false

Since each of `fast` and `slow` can be incremented at most `n` times total before reaching the end of the array, the "repeatedly" part is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array of pairs A={(a[0], 0), (a[1], 1), ..., (a[n-1], n-1)}
2. Sort A,
3. For every (a[i], i) in A, do a binary search to see if there's a (a[i] * 2, j) pair or not. We can do this, because A is sorted.

Step 1 is O(n), and step 2 and 3 are O(n * log n).

Also, you can do step 3 in O(n) (there's no need for binary search). Because if the corresponding element for A[i] is at A[j], then then corresponding element for A[i+1] cannot be in A[0..j-1]. So we can keep two pointers, and find the answer in O(n). But anyway, the whole algorithm will be O(n log n) because we still do sorting.

Comment: Step 1 seems superflous... You are not using the second value of the pairs for anything.

Comment: I think the algorithm should return the indexes i and j. That's the reason for second element.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array is a good option - O(nlogn), assuming you don't have some fancy bucket sort option.

Once it's sorted, you need only pass through the array twice - I believe this is O(n)

Create a 'doubles' list which starts empty.

Then, For each element of the array:

- check the element against the first element of the 'doubles' list

  - if it is the same, you win
  - if the element is higher, ditch the first element of the 'doubles' list and check again
- add its double to the end of the 'doubles' list
- keep going until you find a double, or get to the end of your first list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a balanced tree, but it uses extra space but also does not harm the array.

Starting at `i=0`, and incrementing `i`, insert elements, checking if twice or half the current element is already there in the tree.

One advantage is that it will work in `O(M log M)` time where `M = min [max{i,j}]`. You could potentially change your sorting based algorithm to try and do `O(M log M)` but it could get complicated.

Btw, if you are using comparisons only, there is an `Omega(n log n)` lower bound, by reducing the element distinctness problem to this:

Duplicate the input array. Use the algorithm for this problem twice. So unless you bring hashing type stuff into the picture, you cannot get a better than `Theta(n log n)` algorithm!