# Check if there exists A[i] = 2A[j] in a sorted array A

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a question similar to this question: [check if there exists a[i] = 2*a[j] in an unsorted array a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957310/check-if-there-exists-ai-2aj-in-an-unsorted-array-a) with a few modifications.

> The input is an array A[1...n] of n positive numbers sorted in
>   increasing order.
>
> The problem is to determine whether there is a pair of indices i and j
>   such that A[i] = 2A[j].
>
> Design and analyze an O(n) time in-place algorithm for this problem

The problem would be simple if I could store the double of every element in an auxiliary data structure and loop through comparing the values to the original array values, but the in-place specification prohibits that. The best I have been able to come up with is O(nlogn) where for each of the n elements I do a binary search for the double of that element, but I can't wrap my head around any faster way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `A` is increasing, so:

1. `i > j`
2. if `A[i] > 2 * A[j]`, `(i, k)` with `k <= j` is not valid pair
3. if `A[i] < 2 * A[j]`, `(k, j)` with `k <= i` is not valid pair

So the algorithm goes as the following python code:

```
def foo(a):
    i = 1
    j = 0
    n = len(a)

    while n > i > j:
        if a[i] == 2 * a[j]:
            print("a[{}] = 2 * a[{}]".format(i, j))
            i += 1
        elif a[i] < 2 * a[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
            if i == j:
                i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
i = 1
j = 1
while j <= n and 2 * A[i] <> A[j]
    if 2 * A[i] < A[j]
        i = i + 1
    else /* 2A[i] is greater than A[j] */
        j = j + 1
if j <= n
    print i, j
```

This algorithm uses the following features

1. If 2A[i] < A[j] a solution for the lower element could lay in the interval [i + 1, ..., j - 1]
2. If 2A[i] > A[j] a solution for the upper element must lay in [j + 1, ..., n]

The loop takes at most 2 *n* steps, and thus this algorithms needs *O*(*n*) steps.